# Tag issue after deletion of Item from Collection View

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I implemented a collection view in my app.

Collection cell contains a button called delete button for an item.
After deletion a item the tags are not updated, so, If i delete an second item  then it will delete a next to it i.e. tag.

My code is as follow:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GradientCell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIButton *btn_close=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn_close setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 00, 18, 18)];
    [btn_close setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_close addTarget:self action:@selector(delete_image:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn_close.tag=indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}

-(void)delete_image:(UIButton*)sender
{
[self.col_view performBatchUpdates:^{
            [arr_images removeObjectAtIndex:sender.tag];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
        [self.col_view deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is DON'T use the row as your tag!!
You should save in the 'tag' any other information, that later can be converted to a row number. For example you can save the image in your 'arr_images', ideally you should store a pointer to the object that is being represented by that cell.

And when you want to remove the object you should use that object to re-construct the indexpath

```
xxxx = [arr_images indexOfObject:sender.tag];
NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:xxxx inSection:0];
[self.col_view deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
```